# Remove rows with the least frequent value in a column grouping by other columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a *pandas dataframe* with **inconsistent rows**. In the example below `key1` and `key2` are two values which put together must be unique, so the couple `(key1 ,key2)` is the primary key and should appear once in dataframe, while `info` is a binary information of `(key1 ,key2)` and could be `T` or `F`. Unfortunately `(key1 ,key2)` are repeated in the dataframe and sometimes they have `info=T` and other times `info=F`, which is obviously an error.

To remove repetitions I'd like to adopt this reasoning: I'd like to count how many times (for the same couple `(key1 ,key2)`) `info` is `T` and how many times `info` is `F` and

1. if the frequencies are different (most of the time) **keep
   only one of the rows that have the most frequent value** between `T`
   and `F` with a function like `df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["key1","key2"] , keep = "first")` in which `first` should be the
   row with most frequent value of `info`.
2. If instead 50% of
   rows has `info=T` and 50% has `info=F`, I want to **remove all of
   them**, because I have no idea which is the right one with a function
   like `df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["key1","key2"] , keep = False)`.

I don't know how to do this kind of filter because I want to keep 1 row if one case and 0 rows in the other, depending on the values of a specific column within groups of similar rows.

**Desired behaviour**

In:

```sh
     key1  key2    info
0    a1    a2      T 
1    a1    a2      T #duplicated row of index 0
2    a1    a2      F #similar row of indexes 0 and 1 but inconsistent with info field
3    b1    b2      T 
4    b1    b2      T #duplicated row of index 3
5    b1    b3      T #not duplicated since key2 is different from indexes 3 and 4
6    c1    c2      T 
7    c1    c2      F #duplicated row of index 5 but inconsistent with info field
```

Out:

```sh
     key1  key2     info
0    a1    a2       T # for(a1,a2) T:2 and F:1
3    b1    b2       T # for(b1,b2) T:2 and F:0
5    b1    b3       T # for(b1,b3) T:1 and F:0
                    # no rows for (c1,c2) because T:1 and F:1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` and use `pd.Series.mode` to get the modal value. [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) will return the modes in the case of ties, so this allows us to remove these cases with `drop_duplicates` as we expect only a single mode for each unique `['key1', 'key2']`.

```
import pandas as pd

(df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['info']
   .apply(pd.Series.mode)
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates(['key1', 'key2'], keep=False)
   .drop(columns='level_2')
)

#  key1 key2 info
#0   a1   a2    T
#1   b1   b2    T
#2   b1   b3    T
```

---

The result of the `groupby` + `mode` is:

```
key1  key2   
a1    a2    0    T
b1    b2    0    T
      b3    0    T
c1    c2    0    F   # Tied mode so it gets 2 rows with the last
            1    T   # index level indicating the # of items tied for mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create two temporary column that calculate the `count` and `max` of the groups. Then, filter out rows where the group's `count` does not equal the `max` (i.e. more than 50% if you only have `T` and `F` values) and then `drop_duplicates()`. The final piece of logic is to filter out `[key1 , key2]` values where 50% are `T` and 50% are `F`. For that, use drop_duplicates again, but on a different subset that includes `count`, because if the `count` is the same that means you don't know which one to select as you mentioned in your question. Lastly, drop the temporary `count` column.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'info'])['info'].transform('count')
df['max'] = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['count'].transform('max')
df = (df.loc[(df['count'] == df['max']), ['key1', 'key2', 'info','count']]
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['key1', 'key2','info'])
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['key1', 'key2', 'count'], keep=False)
        .drop('count', axis=1))
```

output:

```
    key1    key2    info
0   a1      a2      T
3   b1      b2      T
5   b1      b3      T
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just my take on it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["a1", "a2", "T"],
                          ["a1", "a2", "T"],
                          ["a1", "a2", "F"],
                          ["b1", "b2", "T"],
                          ["b1", "b2", "T"],
                          ["b1", "b3", "T"],
                          ["c1", "c2", "T"],
                          ["c1", "c2", "F"],], columns =["key1", "key2", "info"])
df = df.groupby(["key1", "key2", "info"]).size().reset_index()
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["key1", "key2", 0], keep=False)
df = df.groupby(["key1", "key2"]).max().reset_index()
df = df.drop(0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby`, `idxmin` and `idxmin`:

```
df_ = df.groupby(["key1","key2"]).info.value_counts().unstack(level=2, fill_value=0)
df_max = df_.idxmax(axis=1)
df = df_max.loc[df_max!=df_.idxmin(axis=1)].reset_index(name='info')

print(df)
  key1 key2 info
0   a1   a2    T
1   b1   b2    T
2   b1   b3    T
```